# recursive c-type array dereferencing template

Tags: arrays, templates

Am trying to make template functions, that recursively dereferences an array if still possible, but its dereferenced already before test.
How can I go about this?

```
template <typename T>
int countLayer(T &a){
    if (sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)) return countLayer(*a)+1;
return 1;}
```

even that one false already

```
template <typename T>
int countLayer(T &a){
    if (false) return countLayer(*a)+1;
return 1;}
```

just looked around and found `type_traits`,
but rather not use any extra libraries for a function as essential.

Comment: Try `if constexpr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...okok found it:

```
int countLayer(int &a){ return 0; }
int countLayer(double &a){ return 0; }
int countLayer(char &a){ return 0; }

template <typename T>
int countLayer(T &a){
    return 1+countLayer ( *a);
return 1;}
```

..so this way the normal unary typs of countLayers-Funktion are allready defined and only the arrays need to be generated, so i avoid not being able to dereference an unary, and thats cool;P
..obviously this is quite dangeous cause i could pass any type no declared ahead, but still.
...the idear all together is not to count layers but to make a general output or so ...sort of handling each element in an array.

thanks "n.m" but no use there - but i get it ..it needs to basically be a sort a constexpr to work with templates, but proove me wrong ...please;P
anyway cheers "n.m"

Answer (score 0):

..just an Example:
this:

```
void printArray(const int (&a)[2][2][4]){
    cout<<'{'; bool aAf=true;
    for (const int (&aA)[2][4]: a){         if (aAf) aAf=false; else cout<<", "; cout<<'{'; bool aBf=true;
        for (const int (&aB)[4]: aA){       if (aBf) aBf=false; else cout<<", "; cout<<'{'; bool aCf=true;
            for (const int (&aC): aB){      if (aCf) aCf=false; else cout<<", ";
                cout<<aC;}
            cout<<'}'; }
        cout<<'}'; }
    cout<<"}\n";    
}
```

..gets reduced to:

```
void printA(int &a) { cout<< a; };

template <typename T>
void printA(T &a) {
    cout << '{';
    bool first=true;
    for (auto &aS: a){  if (first) first=false; else cout<<", ";
                        printA(aS); }
    cout << '}';                    
}
```

..and handles any type of array nicely as long as the unary type exists

..just nice and really handy to know;P